# Defining Related Fields for Presentation/Reporting from SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I might be going down the wrong track here, but what I am after is some guidance on what to do for related data in SSAS.

What I am after is, when I create a cube I want to be able to use it for reporting/end users, but my dimension may have a product cube, but what is the appropriate way of bringing in other data like the Product Name, Description, Created Date, etc - information that you may not want to actually drill into, but is related to the axis that you're looking at.

I would need to show some of this information if I was reporting from it, but I can't seem to see a way, and most of the youtube videos, etc seem to go over the real basics on Adventureworks and that's it - so I'm not sure how this works in the real world.

So, in the end they can go into Excel/whatever, and see:

```
Product code      Name      Total Profit
```

Rather than just the code axis, and the profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to see it. We typically call these types of fields "member properties". You create them by setting the AttributeHierarchyEnabled property to False. You use them in Excel as described here (works in Excel 2007 and Excel 2010):

http://blog.davyknuysen.be/2009/08/03/olap-reporting-with-excel-2007-use-member-properties/

Comment: Thanks @Stacia, I checked it out and it worked perfectly - finding the right terminology can be a killer.